# jQuery logic not affecting children inside DIV

Tags: jquery

I have the following DIV's on my page. I am increasing/reducing the width of the LeftDiv (div id="leftc") on mouse over and mouse out

```
<div id="outerwrap">
    <div id="innerwrap">
        <div id="centerc">...</div>

        <div id="rightc" style="font-weight:bold">
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:White;height:10px;top:284px;left:0px"></div>

        <div id="leftc">..</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" ">...</div>
</div>
```

jQuery logic,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#leftc").hover(
            function mouseover() {
                $(this).css({ width: "190px" });
                $("#centerc").css({ "margin-left": "195px" });
            },
            function mouseout() {
                $(this).css({ width: "25px" });
                $("#centerc").css({ "margin-left": "29px" });
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

This words great if the leftdiv does not have children div's, but if it has children div, then they are not affected.

How can I write jQuery so that children div's also reducing and expand as their parent div does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will also change the width of all child divs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#leftc").hover(
            function mouseover() {
                $(this).css({ width: "190px" });
                $("#leftc div").css({ width: "190px" }); // added this line
                $("#centerc").css({ "margin-left": "195px" });
            },
            function mouseout() {
                $(this).css({ width: "25px" });
                $("#leftc div").css({ width: "25px" }); // added this line
                $("#centerc").css({ "margin-left": "29px" });
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

But you shouldn't need to do that. You probably want to check your CSS (use liquid width for child divs.)

Comment: Thank you so so much Anaimi..and why shouldn't I be doing this..Can you tell me what is liquid width?

Comment: Also how can I select all children inside the DIV , irrespective of them being a div or not? For eg: I have a Image inside the child div, but the child div get resized whereas image does not..

Comment: @Musa: To select all descendants, regardless of tag type:
$("#leftc *"); // * matches any tag.
To may only children of #leftc, regardless of tag type:
$("#leftc > *"); // > restricts matching to children of #leftc

Comment: For liquid/dynamic widths you should use percentages, dont use fixed/static widths. To get all children (not only div) see http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children